# Using rclone mount in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, fuse, rclone

I tried to use `rclone mount` in Heroku dyno, but it doesn't seem to work because there is no `fusermount`. And I found [this](https://github.com/kenshin23/heroku-fuse-buildpack), a fuse buildpack for heroku, and it doesn't work too.

I went into dyno's `bash` by `heroku run bash`, and entered these commands

```
# These commands came from: https://github.com/kenshin23/heroku-fuse-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kenshin23/fuse-lib/master/fuse_2.9.2.tar.gz
mkdir -p vendor/fuse
tar -C vendor/fuse -xvf fuse_2.9.2.tar.gz
# These commands came from: https://github.com/kenshin23/heroku-fuse-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile
PATH="$PATH:/app/vendor/fuse/bin"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/vendor/fuse/lib"

rclone mount DRIVE:/foo bar # Assuming rclone is properly configured
```

And I only get these error messages from `rclone mount`:

```
2020/01/02 10:18:49 mount helper error: fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
2020/01/02 10:18:49 Fatal error: failed to mount FUSE fs: fusermount: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Dynos are effectively containers, isolated from the host system. Attempting to alter any system files, will either not work, so we can’t initialize fuse device.

By the way, deploying with Docker may be a brilliant idea.